# display json value in TextView

Tags: java, android, json

I tried to fetch data from JSON API link which look like this:

```
   {  
   movies:[  
      {  
         id:"8236",
         title:"Black Water",
         imdb:"tt5622412",

      }
   ]
}
```

and this is main class MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mSearchResultsTextView;

    int MovieId = 8236;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test2);

        mSearchResultsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_search_results_json);

        makeSearchQuery(String.valueOf(MovieId));
    }

    private void makeSearchQuery(String sortOrder) {
        showJsonDataView();
        new test2.QueryTask().execute(sortOrder);
    }

    private void showJsonDataView() {
        mSearchResultsTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void showErrorMessage() {
        mSearchResultsTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    public class QueryTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<ShashaItem>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<ShashaItem> doInBackground(String... params) {
            if (params.length == 0) {
                return null;
            }

            String searchUrl = params[0];
            URL channelRequestUrl = NetworkShasha.buildUrl(searchUrl);

            try {
                String SearchResults = NetworkShasha.getResponseFromHttpUrl(channelRequestUrl);

                ArrayList<ShashaItem> simpleJsonTVData = JsonShashaDetail.getSimpleMovieStringsFromJson(MainActivity.this, SearchResults);
                return simpleJsonTVData;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ShashaItem> SearchResults) {
            if (SearchResults != null && !SearchResults.equals("")) {


         mSearchResultsTextView.setText(SearchResults.getTitle());
                showJsonDataView();
            }
            else {
                showErrorMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem that there is a red line under the getTitle() method on this line:

```
mSearchResultsTextView.setText(SearchResults.getTitle());
```

in onPostExecute says that

> can't resolve this method

when I debug the app I found the json response correctly return the data of API so the data is come correctly each key with it's value but the problem is with how to display value of title key in a text view without showing the error of getTitle() method

this is the parser code too JsonShashaDetail.java:

```
public final class JsonShashaDetail {

    public static ArrayList<ShashaItem> getSimpleMovieStringsFromJson(Context context, String moviesJsonString)
            throws JSONException {

        final String MOVIES = "movies";
        final String ID = "id";
        final String TITLE = "title";

        ArrayList<ShashaItem> parsedMovieData = new ArrayList<ShashaItem>();

        JSONObject moviesObject = new JSONObject(moviesJsonString);
        JSONArray moviesArray = moviesObject.getJSONArray(MOVIES);

        for (int i = 0; i < moviesArray.length(); i++) {
            int id;
            String title;

            moviesObject = moviesArray.getJSONObject(0);

            id = moviesObject.getInt(ID);
            title = moviesObject.getString(TITLE);

            parsedMovieData.add(new ShashaItem(id, title));

        }

        return parsedMovieData;
    }
}
```

and this is the custom class for items where the getTitle() method exist ShashaItem.java:

```
public class ShashaItem implements Parcelable {

    private int id;
    private String title;

    public ShashaItem(int id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(id);
        out.writeString(title);
    }

    private ShashaItem(Parcel in) {
        this.id         = in.readInt();
        this.title         = in.readString();
    }

    public ShashaItem() {
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ShashaItem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ShashaItem>() {
        @Override
        public ShashaItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ShashaItem(in);
        }
        @Override
        public ShashaItem[] newArray(int i) {
            return new ShashaItem[i];
        }
    };

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

anyone can help?

Comment: Please provide a minimum verifiable code. You have given a lot of code for us to see.

Comment: Is your `getTitle()` method in the same namespace/packages as the main class? If not, have you tried `import your.package.getTitle()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return value is a List<> that one doens't have the method getTitle(), the objects inside the List are instances of ShashaItem and have the method so you have to get one.

Also, you trying to call getTitle in a object that doesnt exists, you need to use the object returned from onPostExecute such:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ShashaItem> SearchResults) {
        if (SearchResults != null && !SearchResults.equals("")) {
           mSearchResultsTextView.setText(SearchResults.get(0).getTitle());
```

Comment: it's just a mistake but what I wrote in real project is like this : mSearchResultsTextView.setText(SearchResults.getTitle()); and the problem of can't resolve method getTitle() appear but now after I add .get(0) with it everything work perfectly! thanks a lot man

Answer (score 3):

In your MainActivity.java I can not see the `githubSearchResults` object at all. Only way you could access method `getTitle()` is when `githubSearchResults` is an instance of `ShashaItem.class`.

So for me there is no problem with parser itself.
 **It is look like `githubSearchResults` is not instantiated so it is not `ShashaItem.class` instance, so it has no method like `getTitle()`**

eg. `MainActivity.java` you should have something like this:

```
ShashaItem githubSearchResults;
```

and in onPostExecute method

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ShashaItem> SearchResults) {
        if (SearchResults != null && !SearchResults.equals("")) {

     githubSearchResults = new ShashaItem();//dont know what scope
                                            // of this object you need
                                            //and what type of constructor
                                            // so I keept it simple :)
     mSearchResultsTextView.setText(githubSearchResults.getTitle());
            showJsonDataView();
        }
        else {
            showErrorMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry it's just a mistake happens  when i tried to copy and edit the code here so the real code I wrote is mSearchResultsTextView.setText(SearchResults.getTitle()); but when I try your solution the method getTitle() resolved  but when debug the project i found the title come with null value,
thanks man the problem solved with @Marcos Vasconcelos answer